# SQL Select Statement for: If there is one match, then show them all

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have the following situation:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is a SQL-Standard statement which gives me every row of "AAA" / "BBB" and the date (grouped by) when there is just a single match with IS NOT NULL in the 4th column. And on the other hand none of them if there is a match with IS NOT NULL in the 4th column for every row. And every row where is a match with IS NULL.

The Output should be:

[image]

I hope it is clear what I mean?

Thank you guys!

Edit:
Tried isaace's solution and with some edit it worked for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM TABLE a
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT COL_1, COL_2 FROM TABLE WHERE COL_4 is null
) b ON a.COL_1 = b.COL_1 AND a.COL_2 = b.COL_2
```

Comment: I could not understand actually, but you can provide the desired output . That can help all others to understand the case better

Comment: I redid my answer after your edit.

Comment: Yes, i edited my post again. And now it works! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your edits, I deleted my previouse answer. I hope I got your question right.

```
select a.* from table a
join
(
    select col1, colb from table where col3 is null
 ) b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when col4 = 'XXX' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by col1, col)
      from t
     ) t
where col4 is null or cnt = 1;
```

This removes the col1/col2 pairs that have more than one "XXX" column.

Comment: As I don't have partition by functionallity available in MS Access. Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: @John . . . The question is EXPLICITLY tagged with SQL Server and T-SQL.  If you have a question about MS Access, you should ask *another* question and tag the question appropriately.

Comment: I never tagged my question with t-sql! :/
look... why should i write "What I'm trying to achieve is a SQL-Standard statement" ?
anyhow... I corrected the flags

Comment: @John . . . As I write this, the question is tagged with "sql-server", not "ms-access".  That makes this a *very* appropriate solution -- in fact, probably better than the other answer in terms of performance.  Window functions have been part of the standard for about two decades, so they are considered very standard SQL.